# How do I find this derivative?

Tags: derivatives

I need to find the derivative of this $[f(x)]^{g(x)}$.What rule of differentiation do I use ?. I don't think the power rule is applicable in this case.

Comment: You can write this as $e^{g(x) \ln f(x)}$, and then differentiate, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, logarithms are useful.
$$h(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$$
$$\ln(h(x))=g(x)\ln(f(x))$$
Now we can use chain rule and product rule.
$$h'(x)\frac{1}{h(x)}=\frac{g(x)f'(x)}{f(x)}+g'(x)\ln{f(x)}$$
$$h'(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}\bigg(\frac{g(x)f'(x)}{f(x)}+g'(x)\ln{f(x)}\bigg)$$

Comment: I remember asking this exact question in my calculus class. Try doing it for logarithms now! It uses a similar technique.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=f^g$.  By the multi-variable chain rule, we have...

$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\partial y}{\partial f}\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial g}\frac{dg}{dx}\\&=gf^{g-1}f'+\ln(f)f^gg'\\&=f(x)^{g(x)}\left(\frac{g(x)f'(x)}{f(x)}+\ln(f(x))g'(x)\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: That's the best way to take a derivative, +1